# What's the current state of GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I am currently working on a complex web application and am finding javascript/jquery development for the certain things to be very challenging.  So I started looking for alternative tools.

I think GWT is probably what I've been looking for.  There has been numerous times during development that I have thought "if only I was programming in Java."  The features I'm wanting mostly revolve around OOP and re-usability that I find difficult to obtain in javascript.

However, I want to get a feeling of how viable GWT is.  I've done some searching and have read some opinions of how GWT was a year ago.  But am curious how things are going now.  Are many developers using it? Is it growing?  Do you see GWT being used years from now?

Comment: Ohloh reports decreasing year-over-year commits: https://www.ohloh.net/p/gwt

Answer (score 21, accepted):

GWT is definitely growing, within Google products to begin with.

- Google Buzz makes use of GWT, as does Google Moderator,
- the new Google Web Fonts v2 is built with GWT.
- There are people from the Orkut team contributing extensively these past weeks to the GWT code base (let UiBinder generate a single big HTML string and then wrap "rendered" subtrees into widgets).
- The new [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum) is built with GWT.
- They're [launching](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-meet-app-engine-app-engine-meet.html) RequestFactory as a mean of sharing the same protocol, and even the same code between your web app (in GWT) and your mobile app (for Android).
- Rovio launched [Angry Birds Chrome](http://chrome.angrybirds.com/) last May, thanks to GWT and [ForPlay](http://code.google.com/p/forplay/) (which makes the same code base in Java compilable to "HTML5", Flash, Java and Android!).
- Apache Wave (successor of Google Wave) still uses GWT for its UI.
- etc.

You can also look at the growth in number of project members over time thanks to the Wayback Machine. Compare [January 2007](http://web.archive.org/web/20070102082527/http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/) with [August 2009](http://web.archive.org/web/20090306102151/http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/), and [now](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/people/list). Ohloh also has some good [figures](http://www.ohloh.net/p/google-web-toolkit/analyses/latest).

Comment: https://plus.google.com/110412141990454266397/posts/ivVepvxCu3g

Comment: is this still current?

Comment: Huh!?! That was 5 damn years ago, edited 4 years ago!

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it's definitely picking up especially with Chromebooks and other web-based systems driving the need for HTML5 apps. Even the new port of Angry Birds to chrome is using GWT:

http://chrome.angrybirds.com/

Evidence:

http://r2045.project-slingshot-hr.appspot.com/fowl/fowl.nocache.js

Comment: More evidence: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7os4DImjK5U